# DrawerTest Cannot find symbol variable dashboard

Tags: playframework-2.0

I tried to follow play 2.1 tutorial on http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide6 but I'm stuck on this line of code

```
@Test
public void newProject() throws Exception {
    drawer.group("Personal").newProject();
    dashboard.await().until(drawer.group("Personal").hasProject("New project"));
    dashboard.await().until(drawer.group("Personal").project("New project").isInEdit());
}
```

I put this code on test/views/DrawerTest.java but I got this error when running play test :

```
zentasks/test/views/DrawerTest.java:32: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : variable dashboard
[error] location: class views.DrawerTest
[error]         dashboard.await().until(drawer.group("Personal").hasProject("New project"));
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing your `DrawerTest` class like this:

```
public Drawer drawer;
public Dashboard dashboard; // <------ Add this

@Before
public void setUp() {
    start();
    Login login = browser.createPage(Login.class);
    login.go();
    login.login("bob@example.com", "secret");
    dashboard = browser.createPage(Dashboard.class); // <------ Add this
    drawer = dashboard.drawer(); // <------ Change this
}
```